# Unity create sprite at runtime in random position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn a 2d image sprite in the screen in random position:

```
        tex = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("pig") as Texture2D;
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
        sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 250, 150), new Vector2(Random.Range(-1.5f, 1.5f), Random.Range(-1.5f, 1.5f)));
        GameObject newSprite = new GameObject();
        newSprite.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        newSprite.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;
        newSprite.AddComponent<ObjectMovement>();
        newSprite.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        SR = newSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        SR.sprite = sprite;
```

However, The placement of the sprite is not accurate and it being spawned in a tiny area, I want it to be in any point in the screen, What should my random range be?

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D game? Also, since `newSprite` has a the newly loaded sprite attached to it, what is `SR` used for? You want to position `SR` or `newSprite`? Please answer each question to get an answer from me

Comment: @Programmer It's a 2D game, and I want to position the game object, positioning the sprite on Sprite.create will also effect the game object position so it doesn't matter isn't it?

Comment: But which GameObject do you want to position? The `newSprite`  or the `SR`.  To me it looks like you want to position `newSprite`. I don't know what `SR` is or used for so I can't answer that. I will provide solution for `newSprite` but you can always change it.

Comment: @Programmer The SR is just to attach the sprite to the gameobject newSprite, isn't it? .. I want to position the newSprite..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert **view** to **world** point with `Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint` then you can use **0** to **1** to represent the screen size with **.5** being the middle point.

Don't try to change the position from `Sprite.Create`. Do it after creating the sprite. Remove the random code in that line of code. The only thing to add is

```
newSprite.transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Camera.main.nearClipPlane + 15f));
```

I will use a code from your last question to answer to make sure there is no other problem in your current code. Tested and it works.

```
Texture2D tex = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("pig") as Texture2D;
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 250, 150), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 40);
GameObject newSprite = new GameObject();
newSprite.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
newSprite.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;
//newSprite.AddComponent<ObjectMovement>();
newSprite.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
SR = newSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
SR.sprite = sprite;
SR.transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
```

Comment: Thanks, That's great.